# how to serialize persistent EventSource connection in javascript for use with localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, eventsource

I'd like to do the following in a browser, so that a persistent connection can be shared between multiple tabs:

```
function newConnection() {
    conn = new EventSource(..)
    localStorage.setItem('myConnection', serializeEventSource(conn))
}

...

function restoreConnection() {
    serialized = localStorage.getItem('myConnection')
    return unserializeEventSource(serialized)
}

function serializeEventSource() {
  // something like JSON.stringify()
}

function unserializeEventSource() { // returns EventSource
}
```

Is this even possible at all (I recognize that even if this can be done, there are probably other issues, such as to determining which tab's javascript will handle a given received message, that would need to be addressed)? if so, how would serialize & deserialize work? I've tried `JSON.stringify()` and jQuery's `$.toJSON()` to no avail.

Comment: This is almost impossible; but you could try to create EventSource/streaming fetch in ServiceWorker ( http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers ), or you could create an EventSource in one tab and communicate with other tab - see https://medium.com/@alex89x/communication-among-iframes-and-tabs-a-working-polyfill-for-broadcast-channel-api-f44d07dcf527#.srwgspaab